# Where can I find source code for tutorials on developer.android.com site?

Tags: java, android

I just started learning android and work on second class [Adding the action bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html).

I followed this tutorial and I see that some files are missing and I have errors on my project.

Is there a place where I can fetch source code for this and other tutorials on developer.android.com.

I searched the site but found no reference where sources can be.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check and import from this path of your own computer.

```
D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\samples
```

i.e go into your sdk -> samples ...

Everything is inside this..

Comment: I checked this but it doesn't contain source code for those tutorials. It contains just samples but they are not related to tutorials.

Comment: each and every program things about android is inside this which is provided by android...dig it ...you can find anything you want..

Comment: These are samples without explanation and you cannot do it yourself like in tutorial. I am beginner I don't understand samples without explanations.

Comment: which thing you want to read just import it..then you can visit documents and tutorials also.. same like our project ..